# What is the Korean Homophonic Group?

Tags: pronunciation

> Equivalent question: What Korean letters won't equal 1?

From: [the homophonic group: a mathematical diversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843966/)
 → This is an exercise from Michael Artin's *Algebra* on, well, abstract algebra. In this exercise for the English language, words are equal if they are homophones, kind of like a formalisation of the [joke that sin(x)/n=6](https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidtheshittymath/comments/7z5e61/sinxn6/). So in English:

- bee=be → This implies e=1 by cancellation of b and e.
- buy=by → This implies u=1 by cancellation of b and y.
- rase=raze → This implies s=z by cancellation of r, a and e.

canvass=canvas → This implies s=1 by cancellation of c,a,n,v,a and s. By canvass=canvas and rase=raze, we have s=z=1.

Eventually, all 26 English letters will equal 1. Apparently, this was done for [French](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1062620828) and [Czech](http://www1.osu.cz/%7Ezusmanovich/topics.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting application of abstract algebra in linguistics, but in the context of the answer to the other link it wouldn't be possible to create any relations A~B in the first place as there aren't Korean characters constructed with different consonants and vowels but sound the same. Even the two most similar sounding vowels ㅔ and ㅐ are strictly speaking pronounced differently.

Answer (score 0):

This game can be applied to Korean. Examples:

- [값](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%B0%92)=[갑](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%B0%91) → This implies ㅅ=1 by cancellation of ㄱ, ㅏ and ㅂ.
- [삶](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%82%B6)=[삼](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%82%BC) → This implies ㄹ=1 by cancellation of ㅅ, ㅏ and ㅁ.
- [묶다](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%AC%B6%EB%8B%A4)=[묵다](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%AC%B5%EB%8B%A4) → This implies ㄱ=1 by cancellation of ㅁ, ㅜ, ㄱ, ㄷ and ㅏ.

I do not think this could be expanded to have all jamo equal 1, especially not the vowels.

Comment: This I think comes close to being the correct answer